# Can tokio be understood as similar to Javascripts event loop or be used like it?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm not sure if `tokio` is similar to the event loop in Javascript, also a non-blocking runtime, or if it can be used to work in a similar way. In my understanding, `tokio` is an runtime for futures in Rust. Therefore it must implement some kind of userland threads or tasks, which can be achieved with an event loop (at least partly) to schedule new tasks.

Let's take the following Javascript code:

```
console.log('hello1');
setTimeout(() => console.log('hello2'), 0);
console.log('hello3');
setTimeout(() => console.log('hello4'), 0);
console.log('hello5');
```

The output will be

```
hello1
hello3
hello5
hello2
hello4
```

How can I do this in tokio? Is tokio meant to work like this overall? I tried the following code

```
async fn set_timeout(f: impl Fn(), ms: u64) {
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(ms)).await;
    f()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("hello1");
    tokio::spawn(async {set_timeout(|| println!("hello2"), 0)}).await;
    println!("hello3");
    tokio::spawn(async {set_timeout(|| println!("hello4"), 0)}).await;
    println!("hello5");
}
```

The output is just

```
hello1
hello3
hello5
```

If I change the code to

```
    println!("hello1");
    tokio::spawn(async {set_timeout(|| println!("hello2"), 0)}.await).await;
    println!("hello3");
    tokio::spawn(async {set_timeout(|| println!("hello4"), 0)}.await).await;
    println!("hello5");
```

The output is

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
hello5
```

but then I don't get the point of the whole async/await/future feature, because then my "async" set_timeout-tasks are actually blocking the other println statements..

Comment: You have to `await` everything at the end of `main`. Tokio won't do it for you - when `main` exits, the event loop is shut down immediately.

Comment: I tried this code locally and on the playground. Same result. How can I achieve the same behavior as in Javascripts event loop in tokio? Is Tokio meant to work like this at all?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8f9f7b60589dc1c5a138ecd6ce70b4e9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: yes, Tokio is meant to work much like the JavaScript event loop. However, there are three problems with your first snippet.

First, it returns from `main()` before waiting for things to play out. Unlike your JavaScript code, which presumably runs in the browser, and runs the timeouts even after the code you typed in the console has finished running, the Rust code is in a short-lived executable which terminates after `main()`. Whatever things were scheduled to happen later won't occur if the executable stops running because it returned from `main()`.

The second issue is that the anonymous async block that calls the `set_timeout()` async function doesn't do anything with its return value. An important difference between async functions in Rust and JavaScript is that in Rust you can't just *call* an async function and be done with it. In JavaScript an async function returns a promise, and if you don't await that promise, the event loop will still execute the code of the async function in the background. In Rust, an async function returns a future, but it is not associated with any event loop, it is just prepared for someone to run it. You then need to either await it with `.await` (with the same meaning as in JavaScript) or explicitly pass it to `tokio::spawn()` to execute in the background (with the same meaning as calling but not awaiting the function in JavaScript). Your async block does neither, so the invocation of `set_timeout()` is a no-op.

Finally, the code immediately awaits the task created by `spawn()`, which defeats the purpose of calling `spawn()` in the first place - `tokio::spawn(foo()).await` is functionally equivalent to `foo().await` for any `foo()`.

The first issue can be resolved by adding a tiny sleep at the end of `main`. (This is not the proper fix, but will serve to demonstrate what happens.) The second issue can be fixed by removing the async block and just passing the return value of `set_timeout()` to `tokio::spawn()`. The third issue is resolved by removing the unnecessary `.await` of the task.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("hello1");
    tokio::spawn(set_timeout(|| println!("hello2"), 0));
    println!("hello3");
    tokio::spawn(set_timeout(|| println!("hello4"), 0));
    println!("hello5");
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(1)).await;
}
```

This code will print the "expected" 1, 3, 5, 4, 2 (although the order is not guaranteed in programs like this). Real code would not end with a `sleep`; instead, it would await the tasks it has created, as shown in Shivam's answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to note that `tokio::spawn(foo()).await` and `foo().await` are not exactly equivalent. Consider a `foo()` which takes too much time and does not yield. In the `foo().await` version other tasks on this thread will not be executed until foo() is done. In the `tokio::spawn(foo()).await`, the execution is yielded, so all tasks will be executed while waiting for `foo()` to complete.

Comment: @OzgurMurat I would argue that a `foo()` which does not yield is buggy and needs to be fixed (for example, by wrapping the parts that take too long in `tokio::spawn_blocking()`). Tokio supports both single-threaded and multi-threaded executors. Relying on another thread executing code that doesn't yield is dangerous even in a multi-threaded context and will grind the system to a halt if multiple coroutines attempt the same trick, and every executor thread ends up blocked.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike JavaScript, Rust does not start the execution of an async function until the future is awaited. It means `set_timeout(|| println!("hello2"), 0)` only creates a new future. It doesn't execute it at all. When you await it, only then it is executed. `.await` essentially blocks the current thread until the future is completed which is not "real asynchronous applications". To make your code concurrent like JavaScript, you can use [`join!`](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/06_multiple_futures/02_join.html) macro:-

```rust
use tokio::join;
use tokio::time::*;

async fn set_timeout(f: impl Fn(), ms: u64) {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(ms)).await;
    f()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("hello1");
    let fut_1 = tokio::spawn(set_timeout(|| println!("hello2"), 0));
    println!("hello3");
    let fut_2 = tokio::spawn(set_timeout(|| println!("hello4"), 0));
    println!("hello5");

    join!(fut_1, fut_2);
}
```

You can use [FuturesOrdered](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/struct.FuturesOrdered.html) if want to take feel of `Promise.all`.

More info:-

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21473777
- https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/06_multiple_futures/01_chapter.html

Comment: Or use `join_all` if you want a simpler API.